# How to create a custom spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to make a spinner that does not show the item i choose.For e.g i have a spinner with 3 rows `1` `2` &  `3`. When i choose `2` the spinner should close and i see `2`  on the spinner.I just want to make the spinner behave like a button that just open's spinner . any idea?

Comment: did'nt get it ! plz tel clearly what you want

Comment: Spinners are show you when they closed what you choose. I'm just want to show a image instead spinner

Answer (score 0):

A spinner is just like any other view. If you want it to behave like a Button and start an action when you select an item, you can set a click listener to each of the views inside the spinner.

```
        for (int i =0; i<spinAdapter.getCount(); i++){
        spinAdapter.getView(i, null, null).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do whatever you want here
            }
        });
    }
```

I have not tried this code, but you could give it a go.